# AWS Elasticsearch service get NodeId (Instance ID)

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

I provision AWS Elasticsearch service with Terraform and want to setup CloudWatch alarms for some metrics like CPU Usage etc. also by using Terraform.

In order to do it I have to put `NodeId` to `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` resource:
[image]

The problem is that `aws_elasticsearch_domain` resource doesn't have suitable **Attributes Reference**

And I also haven't found anything suitable in **aws es cli** 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/es/index.html

Any ideas how to get this `NodeId` to use in Terraform?

Comment: Not a complete answer—since it 's missing the TerraForm piece—but maybe a start: `$ aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/ES --metric-name CPUUtilization --dimensions Name=DomainName,Value=your-domain-name | jq '.Metrics[].Dimensions[]|select(.Name=="NodeId")|.Value'` yields the desired node IDs.

Comment: Plus this, maybe: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the nodeId from elasticsearch api instead of relying on aws sdk/cli.

Specifically, you can query the `cat/nodes` api.

Link for reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html

Comment: `GET _cat/nodes` returns hexadecimal IDs and redacted IPs, not the base64 encoded IDs that AWS uses for metrics